# How to create dBase (IV?) file?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access-2007, syntax-error, dbase

I'm trying to create a dBase file since it seems the .TransferDatabase() method in my Export vba code requires the file to exist (keep getting "Field will not fit in record". Assuming due to the file not existing).

I came across one method online using vba:

http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/8.3/samples/geodatabase/creating%20data/createnewdbf.htm

```
Public Function createDBF(strName As String, _
                      strFolder As String, _
             Optional pFields As IFields) As ITable
' createDBF: simple function to create a DBASE file.
' note: the name of the DBASE file should not contain the .dbf extension
'
On Error GoTo EH

' Open the Workspace
Dim pFWS As IFeatureWorkspace
Dim pWorkspaceFactory As IWorkspaceFactory
Dim fs as object
Dim pFieldsEdit As esriCore.IFieldsEdit
Dim pFieldEdit As esriCore.IFieldEdit
Dim pField As IField

Set pWorkspaceFactory = New ShapefileWorkspaceFactory
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Not fs.FolderExists(strFolder) Then
MsgBox "Folder does not exist: " & vbCr & strFolder
Exit Function
End If

Set pFWS = pWorkspaceFactory.OpenFromFile(strFolder, 0)

  ' if a fields collection is not passed in then create one
If pFields Is Nothing Then
' create the fields used by our object
Set pFields = New esriCore.Fields
Set pFieldsEdit = pFields
pFieldsEdit.FieldCount = 1

'Create text Field
Set pField = New Field
Set pFieldEdit = pField
With pFieldEdit
    .Length = 30
    .Name = "TextField"
    .Type = esriFieldTypeString
End With
Set pFieldsEdit.Field(0) = pField
End If

Set createDBF = pFWS.CreateTable(strName, pFields, Nothing, Nothing, "")

Exit Function
EH:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbInformation, "createDBF"

End Function
```

but when trying to run it just for testing out the below line receives "Compile error: User-defined type not defined":

```
Public Function createDBF(strName As String, _
                      strFolder As String, _
             Optional pFields As IFields) As ITable
```

Another thread (from 2003...) suggested a query could be used to Export my Access Table to dBase file:

http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/creating-dbf-file-using-access-vba-code-t1077674.html

but my syntax appears to be off, receiving "Syntax error in query. Incomplete query clause:

```
SELECT ImportedData.*
INTO "...filePath\Personal Project Notes\" "dBase IV;"
FROM ImportedData;
```

If anyone has any ideas to fix these or even a different solution I'm all ears. Again, trying to create the dBase file since my following export code flags the .TransferDatabase() method saying "Field will not fit in record":

**Export Code:**

```
Sub Export()
Dim dbConnection As ADODB.Connection
Dim dbFileName As String
Dim dbRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
Dim xRow As Long, xColumn As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

'Go to the worksheet containing the records you want to transfer.
Worksheets("FeedSamples").Activate
'Determine the last row of data based on column A.
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
'Create the connection to the database.
Set dbConnection = New ADODB.Connection
'Define the database file name
dbFileName = "...filePath\Personal Project Notes\FeedSampleResults.accdb"
'Define the Provider and open the connection.
With dbConnection
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbFileName & _
    ";Persist Security Info=False;"
    .Open dbFileName
End With
'Create the recordset
Set dbRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
dbRecordset.CursorLocation = adUseServer
dbRecordset.Open Source:="ImportedData", _
ActiveConnection:=dbConnection, _
CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, _
LockType:=adLockOptimistic, _
Options:=adCmdTable
'Loop thru rows & columns to load records from Excel to Access.
'Assume row 1 is the header row, so start at row 2.
'ACCESS COLUMNS MUST BE NAMED EXACTLY THE SAME AS EXCEL COLUMNS
For xRow = 2 To LastRow
    dbRecordset.AddNew
    'Assume this is an 8-column (field) table starting with column A.
    For xColumn = 1 To 69
        dbRecordset(Cells(1, xColumn).value) = Cells(xRow, xColumn).value
    Next xColumn
    dbRecordset.Update
Next xRow

'Close the connections.
dbRecordset.Close
dbConnection.Close
'Release Object variable memory.
Set dbRecordset = Nothing
Set dbConnection = Nothing
'Optional:
'Clear the range of data (the records) you just transferred.
'Range("A2:H" & LastRow).ClearContents
MsgBox "Test"

Dim acx As access.Application
Set acx = New access.Application
acx.OpenCurrentDatabase ("...filePath\Personal Project Notes\FeedSampleResults.accdb")
acx.DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "dBase IV", "...filePath\Personal Project Notes\", acTable, "ImportedData", "TEST.DBF"
acx.CloseCurrentDatabase


End Sub
```

The filepath is correct, but currently TEST.DBF does not exist. I was originally assuming the method created the file for me...

**EDIT:**

After some testing, I shrunk my Access table down to 15 fields TEXT at 255 characters. When running the Access gui-Export I was successfully able to create a dBase IV file with my 15 fields. Since I then had my .DBF file, I placed it in my .TransferDatabase() file path and my vba code in Excel executed successfully from Excel to Access to dBase file!

I now just need to figure out what the issue is when exporting 69 records versus 15....

Any thoughts?

Comment: Just for kicks began using the gui-export-to-dBase in Access and playing around with my fields. Since I keep getting the "Field will not fit in record" error, I tried deleting a few fields. I currently have a total of 69 fields (discluding the ID field) all set as Text - 255 chars. When I deleted all but 11 fields, the export to dBase IV worked!? Anyone have ideas on this? Know the limitations of dBase fields/files? This is my first attempt at dBase files ever.

Comment: What's your original problem? You're trying to `.transferdatabase()` from what to what?

Comment: Since Excel 2007 no longer supports export to .DBF, I have to take records in Excel, Export to Access, and I'm trying from my Excel vba code to then Export the Access Table into a dBase file. The .TransferDatabase() was giving me a "Field will not fit in record" error. With 11 fields at 255 characters, my code will now execute successfully from Excel, to Access, into dBase file. Trying to export all 69 fields though still gives me the "Field will not fit in record" error.

Comment: There is an SaveDBF add-in that restores the Excel to .dbf functionality [HERE](http://thexlwiz.blogspot.co.uk/)

Comment: Also, aren't `dBase` char fields length 254, rather than 255?

Comment: Yes, but that is not free. That would probably be the EASIEST solution but I'm sure my higher-ups would prefer a free solution. In regards to char filed lengths in dBase, I have no clue. Completely new to dBase files. If you check my Edit to the post I have made SOME progress. After some more experimentation, I've found that I can export my ID field (AutoNumber) plus 15 fields (Text - 255 characters). However, as soon as I try to export even 1 additional Text field, I receive the "Field will not fit in record" error.

Comment: Unless you work *very* cheaply, you've probably spent more than the $35 cost trying to fix the issue. :o)

Comment: I'm salary, so yes, in one week the cost of me developing has already exceeded 35, but still :P I'm so close now I'd really hate to give up and just buy the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following procedure worked for me in Access 2010.

I keep a working directory called `C:\__tmp\` for messing around with things. I created a new subfolder named `dbfTest` which starts out empty:

```
C:\__tmp\dbfTest>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 2A3E-1929

 Directory of C:\__tmp\dbfTest

2013-06-07  10:49    <DIR>          .
2013-06-07  10:49    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  305,532,461,056 bytes free
```

Then I ran the following VBA code in Access to export my "Clients" table to "CLIENTS.DBF"

```
Sub dbfExportTest()
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "dBase IV", "C:\__tmp\dbfTest\", acTable, "Clients", "CLIENTS"
End Sub
```

When that finished my `dbfTest` folder contained the following:

```
C:\__tmp\dbfTest>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 2A3E-1929

 Directory of C:\__tmp\dbfTest

2013-06-07  10:55    <DIR>          .
2013-06-07  10:55    <DIR>          ..
2013-06-07  10:55             5,942 CLIENTS.DBF
2013-06-07  10:55               863 CLIENTS.DBT
2013-06-07  10:55                59 CLIENTS.INF
2013-06-07  10:55             6,144 CLIENTS.MDX
               3 File(s)         12,145 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  305,532,440,576 bytes free
```

My [Clients] table in Access has the following structure:

```
FieldName  Type
---------  ----------
ID         AutoNumber
LastName   Text(255)
FirstName  Text(255)
Email      Text(255)
Selection  Yes/No
intCol     Number(Long Integer)
dtmCol     Date/Time
Comments   Memo
```

### Edit re: comment

dBASE_III and dBASE_IV files apparently have a maximum record length of 4,000 bytes (ref: [here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~varun/cs315p/xbase.txt)). This suggests that a dBASE_IV file could not hold more than 15 Text(254) fields. Possible workarounds include:

- change the table structure in Access to shorten Text(255) fields if they are not using all 255 characters, or
- convert `Text()` fields to `Memo` prior to exporting, since dBASE, like Access, only stores a link to the Memo field in the main table (10 bytes for dBASE).

Comment: If you check my Edit to the post I have made SOME progress. After some more experimentation, I've found that I can export my ID field (AutoNumber) plus 15 fields (Text - 255 characters). However, as soon as I try to export even 1 additional Text field, I receive the "Field will not fit in record" error. Any ideas on this? I am completely new to dBase files.

Comment: Have a look at [THIS](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/microsoft-access/376415-error-exporting-data-dbf-file.html) thread which seems to have a solution to a very similar issue.

Comment: I came across that thread earlier, but I wasn't sure if the issue would be EXACTLY the same since my table isn't "linked". I'm running Excel vba code to connect to the database and export my excel records into the table. I then close the connection and open the database to run the .TransferDatabase() method.

Comment: @Gord Thompson, this prompts some other (probably confusing) questions, but here goes: 1. I do not know which dBase format the final product is to be in, so out of curiosity, what is the maximum record length of a dBase 5 file? I can look into shortening the fields certainly (may even work) but sadly about 40 of my fields I do not even have sample data for to know the limits. 2. So if I converted the larger fields to memo and tried exporting, no matter the length, each field record of memo would be only 10 bytes?

Comment: @Gord Thompson, I'll have to get more sample data from my users, but after shrinking all the fields down, I am now successfully export 69 fields! :) Thanks for the help!